# Check if item in dictionary exists in csv file

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary, with one value per key, and a csv.
What I want to do is check if the key is in the csv file, if this is true i want to return/print the value of that given key.
This is what I did so far:

```
 for key in dico:
     for row in csv_file:
         if key == row[2]:  
             print (dico.get(key))
```

EDIT

row[2] is because I only want to compare with the 3rd column

This is my csv file:

```
SACOL2705;SA2705; AAW37353.1
SACOL2702;SA2702; AAW37350.1
SACOL2703;SA2703; AAW37351.1
SACOL2700;SA2700; AAW37348.1
```

This is my dictionary:

```
{'AAW36317': 'WP_000691766', 'AAW36318': 'WP_000868999', 'AAW37348.1': 'WP_000864799' }
```

In this case the output should be:

```
WP_000864799
```

Because AAW37348.1 is in both files.

Comment: What is the `[2]` for?

Comment: Why do you call `if` a loop? Do you know what the word "loop" means?

Comment: Is `cs_file` a list or a string?

Comment: shouldn't ```if key2 == row[2]: ``` be ```if key == row[2]:  ``` (assuming you are searching the third column in the csv file for the given key in your dict)

Comment: There's nothing here that would make it finish after printing the first match. If you're only printing one thing, then that's all the matches there are.

Comment: Note that without extra work, you can loop over a file only once but over a dict multiple times.

Comment: Can you show an example of the dictionary and CSV file, and what you expect the output to be?

Comment: I know for sure that there are more than one match between both files, I checked manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you get to the end of the first `for row in cs_file:` loop, there's nothing left to read in the file. So the next iteration has nothing to read.

You can see back to the beginning of the CSV file. You need to do that on the underlying file object.

```
with open("filename.csv") as f:
    cs_file = csv.reader(f)
    for key in dico:
        for row in cs_file:
            if key2 == row[2]:  
                print (dico.get(key))
        f.seek(0)
```

Or you can read the entire CSV file into a list in memory:

```
with open("filename.csv") as f:
    cs_file = list(csv.reader(f))
    for key in dico:
        for row in cs_file:
            if key2 == row[2]:  
                print (dico.get(key))
```